# Does this mean "Jerry was being taken aback by a stranger”

Tags: sentence-meaning, gerund-clauses

> Jerry Paiz recalled **being taken aback** by the stranger on the street
> corner inquiring about compassion.
> David Begnaud, CBS News, 30 June 2023

Does this mean Jerry *was* being taken aback by a stranger who was on the street corner inquiring about compassion?
I know it's weird, I want to make sure I understand correctly.

Comment: It's not weird. If you understand what it means ***to be taken aback*** **by something or someone**, the rest is easy. Where is your confusion?

Comment: Any verb that comes after *recall* is in the **gerund form**.

Comment: The continuous form is *necessary* in initial *recalled **being** taken aback,* but it's not at all idiomatic to include it in your *Does this mean Jerry **was being** taken aback*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means, assuming that Jerry's recollection is correct, that Jerry was taken aback by a stranger.  It would be odd to use a continuous "was being", and it doesn't match the quote.

Comment: Being taken aback is normally an instantaneous reaction, so it's unusual to use continuous tenses ("he was being taken aback"!? for how long exactly!?), but sometimes that's required by the context/grammar.

Comment: @StuartF Can you give an example when it's required by the grammar?

Comment: A possible context is a person describing a photo of someone in a state of shock.  "Here's a photo of me and Mary at our wedding.  I've got that look on my face because I'm being taken aback as Mary has just told me that she's pregnant".

Comment: I would not use the continuous for that, @JamesK.  If I described the scene in the present tense then I would say "I've got that look on my face because I *am* taken aback [...]".

Answer (score 14):

When we use the verb "recall" like that, it takes a *gerund* (usually ending with "-ing").

So,

- **I *looked* scared** ⟶ **I recall *looking* scared**
- **I *thought* hard** ⟶ **I recall *thinking* hard**
- **I *was* young** ⟶ **I recall *being* young**
- **I *was* taken aback** ⟶ **I recall *being* taken aback**

Comment: Nice answer with examples! And just like simple past -> present gerund, you can also have pluperfect -> perfect gerund. Like, "I had looked scared" becomes "I recall having looked scared" and "I had been taken aback" becomes "I recall having been taken aback."

Answer (score 1):

The use of the continuous is weird with something as instantaneous as shock or surprise. But people do say:

> I recall being shocked by a knock on the door at 11PM.

There, with **recall**, it loses the sense of the continuous (or perhaps recollection allows us to "replay" the memory continuously, or allows us to *freeze-frame* the incident.) We wouldn't say:

> I was being shocked by a knock on the door at 11PM.

To be "taken aback" is similar to being "startled" in that it is our response to a situation. It means "to be shocked, to be surprised".

Someone or something can startle us.  Someone can surprise us. Someone can shock us. Those transitive verb active voice uses are common.

But [not until very recently](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+took+him+aback%2Cit+took+her+aback%2Cit+took+them+aback%2Cshe+took+him+aback%2Che+took+her+aback&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) has there been a transitive verb active voice "to take someone aback" in modern English, and I have never heard anyone use the verb in an active voice transitive manner.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  **was being eaten** in *I was being eaten alive by mosquitoes*  is a past continuous passive construction.

Comment: Do I call it a tense?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your answer and appeared to have glossed over *There, with recall, it loses the sense of the continuous* I'll delete my previous comments.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Sometimes things get testy on these sites and we come "loaded for bear"  :-)